# Is there a way in "Copy Files Tasks" in TFS to Copy the files and also it's Folders and subfolders with it's files

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, continuous-deployment

For this example below, I want to use the "Copy Files Tasks" to copy the "Project1" and it's subfolder namely "bin", "ConfigFiles", etc. that contains it's files. But can also copy the folder in "Project1" as a directory and it's files within, to the Target Destination. I don't want to use the "Windows Machine File Copy" tasks...

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you hover your mouse over the `(!)` icon next to Contents? It explains how to use glob patterns to specify exactly what you want to copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel Mann mentioned, you can find the glob patterns in the task link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

[image]

In addition, since you'd like to copy the "Project1" as well, you need to remove it in `Source Folder` but specify in content.

Sample as below:

[image]

I checked the result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I want to include also the folder structure coming from the source to the target destination.

Comment: It will have the folder structure if you `specify the folder path in the content`. As i shown in the sample code, in the target folder, it will have `Project1` and it's files, subfolder `Project1/bin` and it's files, `Project1/ConfigFiles` and it's files. Let me know if you have any difference.

Comment: Thank you for this. This is now ok. I forgot to uncheck the "Flatten Folders" check box. It is now working.

Comment: Glad to know it's working for you! :) Could you please make is as answer so it could help other who has same query? Thanks in advance!